# Showing a list of new files

Tags: git

I’d like Git to show me a list of “new files” in a certain directory, where by “new files” I mean files that are either untracked or which have been added to the index. In other words, I want a command that will do the equivalent of

```
git status -s some_directory | grep '^\(??\|A \)'
```

Is there a “git-only” way to do this, or should I just stick with using `grep`? I’ve tried

```
git ls-files -o some_directory
```

which works great for showing the untracked files, but I couldn’t find a flag that would also show files that have been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show files that have been added:

```
git diff-index --cached --name-only --diff-filter=A HEAD
```

Unfortunately, I don't think you can get both added and untracked files in one command except by playing tricks with the output of `git status` like you do. `git status` actually runs several sub-commands behind the scenes to get the different classes of files, so you might just need to use your above `git ls-files` command in addition to the `git diff-index` one if you want both outputs.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like `grep` might be the best option for my use case.